# When does the Galois cohomology functor $H^1(Gal(K^{sep}/ -), G(K^{sep}))$ preserve pullback diagrams?

Tags: category-theory, group-cohomology, pullback, galois-cohomology

Fix a field $K$ and a separable closure $K^{sep}$ of $K$. Consider the category of all separable field extensions $K \subset L \subset K^{sep}$ with field inclusions as morphisms.
Consider the first Galois cohomology functor from this category to the category of **Sets**, which sends $L \mapsto H^1(Gal(K^{sep}/L), G(K^{sep}))$ for some fixed $G(K^{sep})$ and where any morphism $f: L \to F$ is sent to the induced morphism $f: H^1(Gal(K^{sep}/L), G(K^{sep})) \to H^1(Gal(K^{sep}/F), G(K^{sep}))$.
My question is:

> Given a pullback diagram in the category defined above
> $$
> \begin{array}{ccc}
> E \times_L F &\to &F\\
> \downarrow & & \downarrow\\
> E & \to & L
> \end{array}
> $$
> under which conditions does the first Galois cohomology functor preserve the pullback diagram?

Additional properties that I am happy to assume if it makes things easier:

- In the pullback diagram, the inclusions $F \subset L$ and $E \subset L$ are finite extensions.
- The fields involved are number fields (i.e. finite extensions of $\mathbb{Q}$).